# using svg line to imitate border of div

Tags: html, css, svg

The **end goal** of this

- use svg line to underscore border of div that contains it
- webkit animation effects dash forwards to imitate border effects
- If possible, the line to "be" the top border of the div

The **problem** is the extra padding below the top of the containing div. I do not know the source of the padding. Any tries at `top: 0;` or `margin: 0;` are unsuccessful.

**Actual Results**
[image]

- The line is affected by unknown padding and pushed down a bit

I have an svg line with a div that contains it. This all happens in the ...

**HTML**

```
<div style = "display: inline;" id="divDisplay">

<svg height="1" width="1500">
    <line id="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1500" y2="0" />
</svg>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#divDisplay {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #8dd2d9 , #58c0c7);
  border: 2px solid #dadada;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  height: 100px;


}


#top {

    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin:0;
    stroke: rgb(112,111,111);
    stroke-width: 5;
    stroke-dasharray:1300;
    stroke-dashoffset:1300;
    -webkit-animation: dash-top 3.00s forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes dash-top {
    to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `<svg>` element is inline by default, so `vertical-align` applies and  defaults to [baseline](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/).

A quick fix is to change the `vertical-align` value: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpzpv1m4/3/)

```
svg {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the root cause, but adding the following css solved it.

```
#divDisplay svg
{
    position:absolute;
    top:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wmeLa8tc/

Comment: This works because `position: absolute;` automatically makes an element block-level, and `vertical-align` no longer applies. Adding  `top: 1;` is unnecessary FYI.